# Why didn't the Serpent attack Pocket?

Tags: the-serpent-of-venice

In Christopher Moore's book *The Serpent of Venice*, the fool Pocket is favored by the serpent for...some reason. He seems to figure it out at one point but doesn't share the reason with the reader (or I'm just daft). Why did the serpent favor Pocket rather than just eating him like she did everyone else?